# local dir replace, incoming dir edit upon update?

Tags: wordpress, svn, ubuntu

I have a conflict and I am unsure how to resolve it.

The error I get when doing svn udpate is:

```
Tree conflict on 'wp-content/plugins/eventON'
   > local dir replace, incoming dir edit upon update
Select: (mc) keep affected local moves,
        (r) mark resolved (breaks moves), (p) postpone,
        (q) quit resolution, (h) help:
```

I do not understand what this is trying to tell me.

I would like it to replace the local version of the web server's plugins/eventON with the version that is in the SVN repo.

*Background info:
The error message may be the result of deleting the folder that was being versioned through Wordpress admin panel, and then copying another one in the same location (a bad attempt at updating a plugin while forgetting how SVN works).*

Answer (score 0):

I guess that running the update through Wordpress deleted the `.svn` folders that were present in the plugin (the needed stuff for SVN to work properly).

So you could delete the new, unversioned `eventON` folder that you have copied in your repo, and run a `svn update` from one directory above (`wp-content/plugins`), in order to retrieve the old, versioned plugin.

If it does not work, it may be easier to delete the repository and checkout a fresh version...

Then, you will be able to update your plugin manually through SVN, and commit it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you already know that you want the server's version and not the local, this shouldn't be too difficult to resolve.

1. Identify which files are conflicted with `svn status`.
2. Since you want to keep the repository's version, you probably want to remove any conflicted files that svn has *added* from your working copy. They will have an `A` next to them in the output of `svn status`.  In your case you should probably back them up first, since svn can't get them back for you since they're not in the repo yet. Now use `svn delete --force my/fileToDelete`. You don't need to `delete` anything not related to the tree conflict if you have made other changes you want to keep.
3. Run `svn resolve --accept=working my/treeConflictFolder` on the remaining folder that is conflicted (it will have a capital `C` next to it in the output of `svn status`)

The tree conflict should now be resolved, so you should be able to commit and update normally.

Further reading: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html